# What is the best practice to select users from DB ordered by online?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-performance

I have table 'user', which has about 1 million users. I have query which select online users like this

```
select *, CASE WHEN abstime ( last_login_time + 600 ) >= now ( ) 
          THEN 3 ELSE 1 END AS onsitegen 
from user where blocked=0 order by onsitegen desc limit 3;
```

But it's too slow and I understand why. It's because I use order by onsitegen.

But what another method to select online users you can advise?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the query is supposed to achieve. You want 3 random users from the ones that logged in the last 600 seconds, and if there aren't at least 3, then fill up with any other random users from the database?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Joachim Isaksson, yes, it's exactly.

Comment: An addition to your where clause restricting records to the last day or so should help.

Comment: I don't know postgresql, but shouldn't that + 600 be - 600 if you are looking back 600 seconds?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten all the important details, like `explain analyze` results, PostgreSQL version, etc. Edit the question to add the details, reply in comments when done please. For more advice see _a_horse_with_no_name's link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX abc ON users( blocked, last_login_time );
```

and then try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT U.*, 3 As onsitegen
  from users u
  WHERE u.blocked = 0
    AND u.last_login_time >= now() - 600 * interval '1' second
  LIMIT 3
) x
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT U.*, 1 As onsitegen
  from users u
  WHERE u.blocked <> 0
    AND u.last_login_time < now() - 600 * interval '1' second
  LIMIT 3
) y
ORDER BY onsitegen DESC
LIMIT 3
```